# Why can my node app not find socket.io-client (Cannot find module 'socket.io-client')

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I am trying to setup node, express, and socket.io on an Amazon EC2 instance. I did the following.

```
nvm install 6.11.5 //(node)
npm install express -g
npm install socket.io
npm install socket.io-client
```

ERROR:

```
module.js:471
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
 at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
 at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/server/server.js:3:10)
 at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Here is the beginning of my server.js file (it is in server/server.js).

```
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io-client');  <--- this is where error happens
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');
```

If I do `npm list socket.io-client`

I get the following

```
myapp@1.0.0 /home/ec2-user/server
├─┬ socket.io@2.0.4
│ └── socket.io-client@2.0.4  deduped
└── socket.io-client@2.0.4
```

Comment: Is your server.js file in the same directory as you where you installed socket.io-client with npm install socket.io-client?  I note that you installed express globally so it will be found from anywhere, but the only explanation I can think of is that you did not install socket.io-client in the same directory where your server/server.js file is located.  Can you show a directory hierarchy that shows both server.js and where you installed socket.io-client?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I use forever also. So I removed my forever.log file npm clean cache, npm install socket.io-client, npm init, restarted forever and now I am getting an error further down the file for express. So I think it is fixed as I made it past the socket.io-client line of code. All locally within my /server dir (no more global).

Comment: What does forever have to do with anything?  When debugging a core problem like this, you shouldn't be starting it with forever as it just gets in the way of testing.  Use forever when you're done testing and you want to deploy.  Is there an answer to this question?  A question should either be finished with an answer or deleted if you figured it out, but there's no meaningful answer to write.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on forever. I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I use forever also. So I removed my forever.log file npm clean cache, npm install socket.io-client, npm init, restarted forever and now I am getting an error further down the file for express. So I think it is fixed as I made it past the socket.io-client line of code. All locally within my /server dir (no more global).

Comment: So, what do you conclude was the actual cause of the problem?

Comment: I believe the npm cache was not seeing socket-io installed locally and it was not seeing the path to the global install as I was referencing the local one in my code. Even after I changed the reference it wasn't seeing the global one. I guess because of the cache.